# How download large file chunk by chunk using range and refresh buffer page to merge next chunk with before downloaded chunk?

Tags: php, curl, merge, range, chunks

My server have limitation client download. My server allow to client download less then 4mb file. If file size is bigger then server kill download process. So i wanted to download large file chunk by chunk using range to splits file sizes. Server not allowed bigger size file download so when php code outputted all chunks buffer in same page then server catch it bigger file. So i wanted to refresh buffer page 3.999mb by 3.999mb. Every time 3.999mb buffer will be loaded and i will able to download full file by merge before download chunk to new request next chunk.

**Example:**

> total file size is: 10mb, Now i want to start download in first chunk
>   3.999mb then auto refresh page with new request next 3.999mb range and this next range will merge with first 3.999mb and then auto refresh with new request next
>   range 2.2mb and merge it before downloaded 7.998mb. Total downloaded
>   10mb (full file).
>
> NB: i don't want to use javascript for auto refresh (javascript not supported on my work). I want to use php
>   for auto refresh to new request/load next range.

I tried below code to do that, but below code just downloaded first chunk and not refresh with new request next range in download process.

```
<?php
session_start();
if (!isset($_SESSION['ranges'])) $_SESSION['ranges'] = 0;

    ini_set('max_execution_time', 0);

    $url  = $_GET['url'];

    $filesize = getSizeFile($url);
    $chunksize = (4*1024*1024)-1;
    $splits = range(0, $filesize, round($chunksize));

    $ranges = '';
    for($i = 0; $i<sizeof($splits); $i++)
    {
        $x = ($i == 0 ? 0 : $splits[$i]+1);
        $y = ($i == sizeof($splits)-1 ? $filesize : $splits[$i+1]);
        $ranges .= $x.'-'.$y.' ';
    }
    $range = explode(' ', $ranges);
    $size = ++$_SESSION['ranges'] % count($range)-1;

    $reloadRange = $range[$size];

    $ch = curl_init();
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_USERAGENT, 'opera mini android');
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_BINARYTRANSFER, true);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, true);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_TIMEOUT, 0);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_CONNECTTIMEOUT, 0);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HEADER, true);
    curl_setopt ($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, array(
        "HTTP/1.1 206 Partial Content",
        "Server: Apache",
        "Accept-Ranges: bytes",
        "Range: bytes= $reloadRange"
    ));

    $result = curl_exec($ch);
    $header_size = curl_getinfo($ch, CURLINFO_HEADER_SIZE);
    $body = substr($result, $header_size);
    curl_close($ch);
    ob_start();
    echo $body;

    $b = ob_get_length();

    if(explode('-', $reloadRange)[0] == 0)
    {
        header('Content-Description: File Transfer');
        header('Content-Type: application/octet-stream');
        header('Content-Disposition: attachment; filename='.basename($url)); 
        header('Content-Transfer-Encoding: binary');
        header('Connection: Keep-Alive');
        header('Expires: 0');
        header('Cache-Control: must-revalidate, post-check=0, pre-check=0');
        header('Pragma: public');
    }

    if(explode('-', $reloadRange)[1] !== getSizeFile($url))
    {
        if($b !== null)
        {
            header("Refresh: 0;");
            //header('Refresh: 0; url=/server/tt?url='.$url);
            exit();
        } else {
            exit;
        }
    } else {
        session_destroy();
        session_write_close();
        exit;
    }

function getSizeFile($url) { 
    if (substr($url,0,4)=='http') { 
        $x = array_change_key_case(get_headers($url, 1),CASE_LOWER); 
        if ( strcasecmp($x[0], 'HTTP/1.1 200 OK') != 0 ) { $x = $x['content-length'][1]; } 
        else { $x = $x['content-length']; } 
    } 
    else { $x = @filesize($url); } 

    return $x; 
} 

?>
```

Thanks

Comment: Will i get solution or not? Here is no genius person?

Comment: i am not getting comment and answer from you?